# Where is the code for control buttons in animate or a repository of composite characters?

Tags: symbols, animate

I am looking for the code for the control buttons of "player" in `animate` package (for example the button which is a square with a right-pointing triangle is used for PLAY button, as expected).

I did not find this in [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or in [comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive).

Is there a repository for the code of characters or logos which appear to be made from two or more existing characters: an example is `\bigoplus` a circle with a plus sign. Some logos, like  `TeX` itself are rather easy to find. Others not so easy.

Here is [an attempt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/relation-symbol-used-by-conway-in-on-numbers-and-games) for some composite math symbols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These "player buttons" are unique to the [`animate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/animate) and are constructed from low-level Postscript commands.

The following MWE provides an interface to the symbols, entirely extracted from [`animate.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.sty) (minus some colour settings). Each of the symbols is `15pt` in width. Since the commands are low-level, they produce a zero-width representation within LaTeX, and can therefore be overlaid to make more elaborate constructs (like the construction of the "symbol" `<||>`).

The interface is provided by `\pstverb` from the [`pstricks` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pstricks). Compile using the sequence `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or `xelatex`:

[image: Animate package "player buttons"]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}%
\makeatletter
\def\@anim@btnend{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1 setlinewidth
  4.5 4 moveto
  9.5 7.5 lineto
  4.5 11 lineto
  stroke
  0 setlinejoin
  10.5 4.4 moveto
  10.5 10.6 lineto
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnstep{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1 setlinewidth
  5 4 moveto
  10 7.5 lineto
  5 11 lineto
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnplay{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1 setlinewidth
  5 4 moveto
  5 11 lineto
  10 7.5 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnpause{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  0 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  0 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  0 14 lineto
  stroke
  2 setlinewidth
  2.2 4 moveto
  2.2 11 lineto
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnminus{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1.0 setlinewidth
  0 setlinecap
  4 7.5 moveto
  11 7.5 lineto
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnplus{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1.0 setlinewidth
  0 setlinecap
  4 7.5 moveto
  11 7.5 lineto
  7.5 4  moveto
  7.5 11 lineto
  stroke
}
\def\@anim@btnreset{%
%  \@anim@bg\space
%  \@anim@fg\space
  0.25 setlinewidth
  1 setlinecap
  1 setlinejoin
  1 1 moveto
  14 1 lineto
  14 14 lineto
  1 14 lineto
  closepath
  stroke
  1 setlinewidth
  7.5 4 moveto
  7.5 11 lineto
  stroke
  0 setlinejoin
  3.5 5 moveto
  7 7.5 lineto
  3.5 10 lineto
  closepath
  fill
  11.5 5 moveto
  8 7.5 lineto
  11.5 10 lineto
  closepath
  fill
  1 setlinewidth
  2 setlinecap
  3 7.5 moveto
  3.5 7.5 lineto
  12 7.5 moveto
  11.5 7.5 lineto
  stroke
}

\def\btnendleft{\pstverb{[-1 0 0 1 15 0] concat \@anim@btnend}}%
\def\btnendright{\pstverb{\@anim@btnend}}%
\def\btnminus{\pstverb{\@anim@btnminus}}%
\def\btnpauseleft{\pstverb{[-1 0 0 1 15 0] concat \@anim@btnpause}}%
\def\btnpauseright{\pstverb{\@anim@btnpause}}%
\def\btnplayleft{\pstverb{[-1 0 0 1 15 0] concat \@anim@btnplay}}%
\def\btnplayright{\pstverb{\@anim@btnplay}}%
\def\btnplus{\pstverb{\@anim@btnplus}}%
\def\btnreset{\pstverb{\@anim@btnreset}}%
\def\btnstepleft{\pstverb{[-1 0 0 1 15 0] concat \@anim@btnstep}}%
\def\btnstepright{\pstverb{\@anim@btnstep}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|Left end:   |~\btnendleft \par
\verb|Right end:  |~\btnendright \par
\verb|Minus:      |~\btnminus \par
\verb|Left pause: |~\btnpauseleft \par
\verb|Right pause:|~\btnpauseright \par
\verb|Left play:  |~\btnplayleft \par
\verb|Right play: |~\btnplayright \par
\verb|Plus:       |~\btnplus \par
\verb|Reset:      |~\btnreset \par
\verb|Left step:  |~\btnstepleft \par
\verb|Right step: |~\btnstepright

\bigskip

\verb!<||> :      !~\btnpauseleft\btnplayleft\hspace{15pt}\btnpauseright\btnplayright

\end{document}
```

---

[`marvosym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) also provides some playback buttons, as shown in Table 209 of Scott Pakin's [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf):

[image]

---

[`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) also provides some playback symbols:

[image]

Requires the use of Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX.