# Buttons in animation package

Tags: animate, button

I want to use the following buttons in latex.

[image]

I try to the instructions in [this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43649/where-is-the-code-for-control-buttons-in-animate-or-a-repository-of-composite-ch). But it gives empty results as follows:
[image]

Comment: the link you shared I guess has already an proper answer for your question.

Comment: Try the code in the link. You will see that it gives empty result.

Comment: The linked code works just fine, but since it uses `pstricks`, you can't use PDFLaTeX for compilation. Use XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or LaTeX (-> dvips -> ps2pdf) instead.

Comment: Jasper you are right. But then some special characters (\mathbf{Phi} etc) doesn't appear  and my font type automatically were changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `pstricks` together with PDFLaTeX, but only with XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or LaTeX (-> dvips -> ps2pdf).

A workaround would be to use some other drawing package to create these symbols. For example Ti*k*Z which can also be used with PDFLaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\NewDocumentCommand{\btnendright}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round, line join=round] 
            (4.5pt,4pt) -- (9.5pt,7.5pt) -- (4.5pt,11pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round] 
            (10.5pt,4.4pt) -- (10.5pt,10.6pt);
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnendleft}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1, xshift=-15pt]
            \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round, line join=round] 
                (4.5pt,4pt) -- (9.5pt,7.5pt) -- (4.5pt,11pt);
            \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round] 
                (10.5pt,4.4pt) -- (10.5pt,10.6pt);
        \end{scope}
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnstepright}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round, line join=round] 
            (5pt,4pt) -- (10pt,7.5pt) -- (5pt,11pt);
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnstepleft}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1, xshift=-15pt]
            \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round, line join=round] 
                (5pt,4pt) -- (10pt,7.5pt) -- (5pt,11pt);
        \end{scope}
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnplayright}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line join=round] 
            (5pt,4pt) -- (5pt,11pt) -- (10pt,7.5pt) -- cycle;
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnplayleft}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1, xshift=-15pt]
            \draw[line width=1pt, line join=round] 
                (5pt,4pt) -- (5pt,11pt) -- (10pt,7.5pt) -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnpauseright}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line cap=butt, line join=round] 
            (0pt,1pt) -- (14pt,1pt) -- (14pt,14pt) -- (0pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=2pt, line cap=butt] 
            (2.2pt,4pt) -- (2.2pt,11pt);
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnpauseleft}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \begin{scope}[xscale=-1, xshift=-15pt]
            \draw[line width=0.25pt, line cap=butt, line join=round] 
                (0pt,1pt) -- (14pt,1pt) -- (14pt,14pt) -- (0pt,14pt);
            \draw[line width=2pt, line cap=butt] 
                (2.2pt,4pt) -- (2.2pt,11pt);
        \end{scope}
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnminus}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=butt] 
             (4pt,7.5pt) -- (11pt,7.5pt);
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnplus}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=butt] 
             (4pt,7.5pt) -- (11pt,7.5pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=butt] 
             (7.5pt,4pt) -- (7.5pt,11pt);
    }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\btnreset}{ }{%
    \tikz[baseline=1pt, overlay]{
        \draw[line width=0.25pt, line join=round] 
            (1pt,1pt) rectangle (14pt,14pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=round] 
             (7.5pt,4pt) -- (7.5pt,11pt);
        \fill[line join=miter] 
             (3.5pt,5pt) -- (7pt,7.5pt) -- (3.5pt,10pt) -- cycle;
        \fill[line join=miter] 
             (11.5pt,5pt) -- (8pt,7.5pt) -- (11.5pt,10pt) -- cycle;
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=butt] 
             (3pt,7.5pt) -- (3.5pt,7.5pt);
        \draw[line width=1pt, line cap=butt] 
             (12pt,7.5pt) -- (11.5pt,7.5pt);
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\verb|Left end:   |~\btnendleft \par
\verb|Right end:  |~\btnendright \par
\verb|Minus:      |~\btnminus \par
\verb|Left pause: |~\btnpauseleft \par
\verb|Right pause:|~\btnpauseright \par
\verb|Left play:  |~\btnplayleft \par
\verb|Right play: |~\btnplayright \par
\verb|Plus:       |~\btnplus \par
\verb|Reset:      |~\btnreset \par
\verb|Left step:  |~\btnstepleft \par
\verb|Right step: |~\btnstepright 

\bigskip

\verb!<||> :      !~\btnpauseleft\btnplayleft\hspace{15pt}\btnpauseright\btnplayright

\end{document}
```

[image]